# Pydanticv2: How have model_json_schema use definitions instead of $defs?

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

Moving from pydantic v1 to pydanticv2, and need the jsonschema to come out using definitions instead of $defs. Anyone know how to do this natively in pydantic without using string replace?

The test models are defined as below

```py
class PropertyReturnStr(BaseModel):
    propertyKey: str
    value: str

class PropertyReturnModel2(RootModel):
    root: list[PropertyReturnStr]
```

Pydantic v1 was able to create json schemas like

```py
{
    "definitions": {
        ...
    },
    "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/PropertyReturnStr"},
    ...
}
```

instead it is coming out like this (... out some uneccessary lines) see `$defs` instead of `definitions`

```py
{
    "$defs": {
        ...
    },
    "items": {"$ref": "#/$defs/PropertyReturnStr"},
    ...
}
```

I tried using a ref_template to fix this like so `PropertyReturnModel2.model_json_schema(ref_template='#/definitions/{model}')` but this led to an output like the following where only the reference line was updated. Word on the street is I may need to use GenerateJsonSchema, i don't know if anyone has any examples of this.

```
{
    "$defs": {
        ...
    },
    "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/PropertyReturnStr"},
    ...
}
```

I'm currently getting around it using this little function here, but would love to do it natively in pydantic.

```py
def get_json_template(model: BaseModel):
    """helper function to get the json schema from the pydantic model"""
    schema = model.model_json_schema()
    json_schema = json.dumps(schema)
    json_schema = Template(json_schema).substitute(
        {"defs": "definitions", "ref": "$ref"}
    )
    return json.loads(json_schema)
```

Comment: Hi! Having the same issue. Have you found a solution for this or understood why it was happening?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems the answer at the moment is: you can't. The literal `$defs` is hardcoded into the type adapter with no way to customize the key name.

https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/3e871258bd5ea7caa7f18c0b810d8b1e915bd8f2/pydantic/type_adapter.py#L452